# JsonCpp can't find file when I use get_current_dir_name()

Tags: c++, json, file-not-found, jsoncpp

I am trying to parse a json file within my program:

```
#include <jsoncpp/json/value.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    std::string plan { get_current_dir_name() };
    plan += "directory/file.json";
    read_json(plan); // A function that reads a json file using jsoncpp
}
```

Output:

```
Error: Json File not found!
```

However when I manually write the entire path:

```
#include <jsoncpp/json/value.h>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    std::string plan { entire_file_path };
    read_json(plan); // A function that reads a json file using jsoncpp
}
```

Output:

```
File found and read!
```

I thought maybe there is a spelling mistake but when I use `std::cout` on both of the paths, there is not a single difference. I'm not sure what is causing this issue.

Comment: Did you verify that `get_current_dir_name` returns a directory with a / at the end? Otherwise you might end up as /home/usernamedirectory/file.json.

Comment: @Botje Yes, I recognized that issue so I decided to add `"/{Remaining_Path}"`, which returns a complete copy of the full path, though it still did not work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Using std::filesystem built-in to C++17:

```
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
fs::path path = fs::current_path() / "directory" / "file.json";
read_json(path.string());
```